# Groovy set text of node that has children

Tags: java, xml, groovy

I have a node in an xml document that has the following general structure:

```
String xml = "
<root>
    <firstNode class="first">SomeText<childNode class="child">SomeMoreText</childNode></firstNode>
</root>"
```

I want to modify the text of the `firstNode` node.  So I want to change the value of "SomeText" to something else, like "NewText".  So the above xml would look like this:

```
<root>
    <firstNode class="first">NewText<childNode class="child">SomeMoreText</childNode></firstNode>
</root>"
```

I can get the `firstNode` node using the `XmlParser` class:

`def firstNode = new groovy.xml.XmlParser().parseText(xml).root[0]`

From the [Node doc](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Node.html) I am able to get the "SomeText" value using `firstNode.localText()[0]` but I can't figure out how to set that text.  Somehow I was thinking of doing `firstNode.setValue()` but I don't know what to pass in that function.

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manipulate the node's children directly `firstNode.children().set(0, "foo")`. Furthermore, the `root` node is implicit, so you need to omit it.

```
String xml = """
<root>
    <firstNode class="first">SomeText<childNode class="child">SomeMoreText</childNode></firstNode>
</root>
"""
def root = new groovy.xml.XmlParser().parseText(xml)
def firstNode =  root.children()[0]
firstNode.children().set(0, "foo")
def nodeAsText = groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(root)
println nodeAsText
```

Try it in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_4_0&codez=eJxtkE0KwjAQhfc5xZBVCpJ6gLTgARRBBUFcFDvVQJpIEvw7vZMUraJZTV7evPkmq-i1PcKtN1AB55wp71ysGdBRnfYhLlyLcDBNCBXPAq9Xrsc13qI6nLRpPw1ZGAxz5wdT-XbVqnxH1kyVw6g0tcUO0o0gLF7hSPXlLolKbnuzbHxALwp5TkXKFPRS5KYRsYKcIPM0j1YUu-menWm9aOzo-1U-Ohj7p8qAUUwnwDvnePEnMpNYqmYh0RHK9wKbqA2FeN0Y_UCRMMeYsY-x_O2v8wQNUYtg)

Comment: yeah you're right on ````root```` silly mistake...  This makes sense and seems to work.  Just to understand more, is the value of a node considered to be its first child? @user16358266

Comment: No, if you look at the code, you can see that a `Node` can contain `Object` as value, and if it has children that is a `NodeList` it contains the children in order. So, if the text was after the `childNode` then it would be at index `1`. Or if you had text after the `childNode` there would be an additional entry at `2` with the text.

Comment: ok.  I think I was incorrectly using the term "value" instead of "text."  But what I understand now is that the text of a Node is considered a child of the node.  Thanks!